# Radio buttons dont work when jquery.html() is used to load dynamic form

Tags: html, jquery, forms, radio-button

http://ano-mag.com/black-foil/ please check this url - click the "Order Now" button on the left side - notice how the radio buttons won't work? I cant figure it out!

Comment: I would recommend posting the relevant code in your question.

Comment: it works fine in a fiddle I know that - something strange is going on

Comment: @JeffJones can you show us the fiddle in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sJpUT/ :)

Comment: It'd be a little nicer if you could reproduce the faulty scenario in the fiddle. `:P`

Comment: well thats just it! i copied the code straight over.. wtf!

Comment: I'm looking through your code, I'd guess it's something to do with your `initAnoBox` function. Did you try commenting the `$('.ano-box').click` function which returns `false`? Just a guess.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté you are absolutely correct! wow I cant believe it didn't keep the other inputs from engaging, just those - wow

Comment: @JeffJones Yes, cancelling DOM events from bubbling up can usually cause some bugs like that, I'm putting up an answer to don't leave this unanswered. =]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reproduced the faulty behavior on your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/sJpUT/1/), it's due to this block of code:

```
$('.ano-box').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Which prevents the `click` event from bubbling up the DOM to your radio buttons. `=]`

**Complementary edit:**

Your text `input`s still gain focus in the faulty scenario because text inputs gain focus in the `mousedown` event, which is properly executed as it fires before the `click` event. The `radio` inputs, however, are checked in the `click` event which is being cancelled by your function. `=]`

Comment: @JeffJones I added a complementary edit in case you were curious as to why the text inputs still gain focus in the faulty scenario, if that's of concern. `:P`